# Java: how to convert from type A to type B?

Tags: java

I'm a java beginner and although I've looked for the topic both here and on Google I haven't found it. I'm sure it has to be there somewhere but it's me who doesn't know how to search. Anyway, here it is:

How can I write methods to convert from string/int/etc. to a class and vice-versa? I'd definitely like that my class conversion be automatic but I can live with less-than-perfect typecast. What I wouldn't be comfortable with is calling class("some string") or class.toString() for converting back and forth from string to class. I'd like it to be as seamless as possible. Here's an example:

I have a *IsFound* class that behaves like a boolean and I use it as a return type in a method; in the method body I return a string like "found" (instead of *true*). You may laugh at me for not using a Boolean but I want to play a little with a custom class/type. Here's some code

```
public class IsFound{

    public boolean found; // field

    public IsFound(String isFound_){
         if(isFound_.equals("FOUND")){
              found = true;
         else found = false;
         }
    }

    public String toString(){
    if(found)   return "found";
    else    return "not found";
    }    
}
```

This is the furthest I could get. I need the converter methods to/from string and for future references I'd like to know whether the converters are applicable for int, char or even other classes.

The solution to extend Boolean is only as a last resort, since I don't know what bloat I'm carrying along -- I want to create the class myself from 0.
EDIT:
I want to be able to use something like:

```
public IsFound parse(String substring_){
    if(search(substring_, string) == true){
        return FOUND; // or return "FOUND";
    {
    return NOTFOUND; // or return "NOT FOUND";
{
```

Currently it gives the error that can't convert from String to IsFound. I want to fill in this gap.

Comment: "I wouldn't be comfortable with calling class("some string") or class.toString() for converting back and forth from string to class" You've just ruled out the very mechanisms that are used in these cases. If you want to convert between two different concrete classes, you have to have code to do so. Which means either calling "new Found(String)" or calling "Found.parseString(String)" or something like that.

Comment: If I can't get something like an autoconvert from java (something seamless like operator overloading in C++) at least I want a convertor method to be able to use the typecast (IsFound)String

Comment: No, you cannot typecast from String to something else. Period. This question smells strongly of a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), that you're not only barking up the wrong tree, but looking in the wrong forest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd also use an enum, here's one that gives you all of the functionality that is in your class.

```
  public enum IsFound{
    // each of these definitions are like calls to the IsFound constructor below
    FOUND("found"),
    NOT_FOUND("not found");

    // string representation
    private final String toString;

    private IsFound(String isFound){
      this.toString = isFound;
    }

    /**
     * @Override
     */
    public String toString(){
      return toString;
    }    


    // I think this is what you want. I'm not sure why you need this, but
    // am including it as I think it gives you what you want. see example below
    public static IsFound convert( String foundString ){
      if( FOUND.toString.equals(foundString) ){
        return FOUND;
      }
      else if( NOT_FOUND.toString.equals(foundString) ){
        return NOT_FOUND;
      }
      else{
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
```

You can use this in the following ways:

```
private IsFound myFoundValue;

myFoundValue = IsFound.FOUND;

System.out.println(myFoundValue.toString()); // "found"

myFoundValue = IsFound.NOT_FOUND;

System.out.println(myFoundValue.toString()); // "not found"

switch( myFoundValue ){
  case FOUND:
    System.out.println("the value is FOUND");
  break;
  case NOT_FOUND:
    System.out.println("the value is NOT_FOUND");
  break;
  default:
    System.out.println("this should never happen");
  break;
}

myFoundValue = IsFound.convert("found"); // IsFound.FOUND

System.out.println( myFoundValue.toString() ); // "found"
```

Comment: I'm struggling to find how do I relate a constant element, be it int, string etc. with a return type of some calling method (see the lower part of my original post.). I'm still searching on the web...

Comment: are you asking how to search for a IsFound by passing a string? Like:
public IsFound convert(String foundString)...

Comment: I added a function that I think does what you want: `convert()`.

Comment: Thanks for the very needed help. Sorry for replying late. Essentially I'm asking for the code to achieve the tiniest (even 0) footprint of a type convertion from string/CONSTANT to java custom class, so that some method is said to return IsFound class, but in its body returns a string/CONST (e.g. "return FOUND;"). In IsFound class, I decide that FOUND means true and NOTFOUND - false. **It wants to be a slimmed down version of a Boolean class with custom value names.**

Comment: Did you take a look at the `convert` function above? I'm not sure if I completely understand what you're asking, but to clarify: in Java, if a method is declared to return `IsFound`, it can only return instances of `IsFound` (or null); you can't return a String, because Java is strongly typed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question smells like a classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in that you appear to be barking up the wrong tree to find a solution to a problem that you may need to understand better. It's an anti-pattern to try to use Strings as a substitute for type, so you're far better off not doing this. For something like this, consider using either a boolean for a two-state type or an enum for a multi-state type.

e.g.,

```
public enum IsFound{
  FOUND, NOT_FOUND, UNKNOWN
}
```

or...

```
public enum IsFound {
   FOUND("Found"), NOT_FOUND("Not Found"), UNKNOWN("Unknown");

   private String name;

   private IsFound(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return name;
   }

}
```

in some other class.

```
private Map<Luggage, IsFound> lostLuggageMap = new HashMap<>();
```

- The enum adds a compile-time type safety that Strings just don't have.
- enums can have properties and behaviors (methods) that are extremely useful.

Comment: It looks like the most straightforward way to do. But it's a little fuzzy for me: can I can use something like: "return FOUND"?

Comment: I'm too noob to even suspect what this means:"private Map<Luggage, IsFound> lostLuggageMap = new HashMap<>();"

Comment: I've never used this type of enum with those parameters. Would you care to explain a little, please? 1. what code do I use to return a string? "return IsFound."not found"" or how? 2. What happens if I input a string different from enum?

Comment: as for returning a string as a type, I don't see why you say it's an anti-pattern. A string is the most self-explaining type. I just want to copy the functionality of a boolean type to be returned as "true" or "false", not 0 and 1, hence the string.

Answer (score 0):

For conversion between "string" representations and POJO ( plain old java objects ), you may want to use serialization to / from a known text format such as JSON ( or XML ).

```
public class Search {

 private boolean found;

 // getters, setters, constructor

}
```

Serialization / Deserialization using Google's GSON library :

```
Search search = new Search();
search.setFound(true);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(search);
// should output : { "found" : "true" } 

// The opposite way , if json is a string equal to { "found" : "true" } 
Gson gson = new Gson();
Search s = gson.fromJson(json, Search.class);
// s has found = true
```

Comment: I don't understand. I've read it like 10 times. I don't know what json and gson are. I need a code so to be able to eventually type "return FOUND;" or "return "FOUND"" and this to be convertible to a class ISFound.

Comment: JSON is a data format ; GSON is a library provided by Google ; Using JSON and GSON you can convert between "strings" and "java objects". For example, a string such as "{ x: 5, y : 6 }" can be converted to a java class Point and back ;